# Select File. Submit. Cannot select file again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, file

I have a form with different fields and with input type="file". I use fileupload jQuery library.

1. Select file
2. Call

   ```
   $('#some_id').fileupload().fileupload(
                       'send',
                       {
                           files: file,
                           url: widget.options.saveVideoUrl,
                       }
                   ).success(
   //...
   ```

   (first fileupload called for init)
3. Try again to select file. Got: No files selected, clear console, etc..

## Upd.1

The problem appear in E-commerce framework **Magento2** in admin area.
The described form appear in such entity like 'slide-out panel'. It means that there is div block and this block wrapped in **aside** block using javascript.

```
<button onclick="jQuery('#new').modal('openModal')" .... >
    <span>New</span>
</button>
```

Here is demo example:

> Admin URL: https://iwdagency.com/magento2/admin
>
> Username: admin
>
> Password:  admin123

Open Products / Catalog / *select any product* / *click on New category*

You should see following panel:

[image]

On such panel I've added by php constructor fields:

```
<div class="admin__field field field-new_video_screenshot " data-ui-id="product-tabs-tab-google-experiment-fieldset-element-form-field-new-video-screenshot">
    <label class="label admin__field-label" for="..." data-ui-id="product-tabs-tab-google-experiment-fieldset-element-file-image-label"><span>Preview Image</span></label>
    <div class="admin__field-control control">
        <input id="...." name="image" data-ui-id="product-tabs-tab-google-experiment-fieldset-element-file-image" value="" title="Preview Image" type="file">
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/backend/tree-suggest',
    'mage/backend/validation'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $.widget('mage.newDialog', {
        _create: function () {
            var widget = this;
            var newVideoForm = $('#new');

            this.element.modal({
                type: 'slide',
                modalClass: 'mage-new-dialog form-inline',
                title: $.mage.__('Create'),
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Create'),
                    class: 'action-primary',
                    click: function (e) {
                        var file = $('#new_screenshot').get(0).files[0];
                        var result = $('#new_screenshot').fileupload().fileupload(
                            'send',
                            {
                                files: file,
                                url: widget.options.saveUrl,
                            }
                        ).success(
                            function(result, textStatus, jqXHR)
                            {
                                var data = JSON.parse(result);
                                data['url'] = $('#new_url').val();
                                data['name'] = $('#new_name').val();
                                data['description'] = $('#new_description').val();
                                $('#media_gallery_content').trigger('addItem', data);
                                $('#new').modal('closeModal')
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }],
            });
        }
    });

    return $.mage.newDialog;
});
```

Comment: Is it a BlueImp fileupload plugin?

Comment: Please add a code snippet, so we can help you.

Comment: Updated. Sorry for much information

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

In my case the problem appear after initialization fileUpload library.

When I selected input:file, the library wasn't initialized (read as **infected**). When I pressed the button, initialization ran and any operations with this input become unavailable.

Solution is following: clone our input before it become infected, than do our operations and at the end replace existing infected input with its healthy copy, created before.